# Windows Recovery Creator cannot see my USB drive

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, system-restore

I am trying to create a Windows recovery drive on a USB key using *Windows Recovery Creator* in Windows 8.1 (64-bit). The computer is a Dell XPS 8700.

When I run *Windows Recovery Creator* I uncheck the "Copy the recovery partition form the PC to the recovery drive". I then click the "Next" button.

After some "Please wait" progress bars I I am presented with the order to "Select the USB flash drive" and a list of drives is shown. However, my USB drive is NOT on the list.

If I go to Windows Explorer I see the USB drive and can read and write to the drive, so I know Windows can access this drive. Furthermore, *Windows Recovery Creator* tells me that it needs 512 MB of space and the drive is a brand new 8GB drive, so space cannot be a concern.

Why is *Windows Recovery Creator* not seeing my USB drive?

Comment: USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 device?  Recovery environment on this disk will be the same environment on an installation disk.  Might be easier just to download the 8.1 installation media through the tool.

Comment: The USB drive is USB 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue as a retail service tech. I found that in some cases the recovery drive needs to be formated as NTFS before it is accepted a usable drive to write the recovery data to. This may have been manufacture specific. I would give that a try. If it dows not work, you call always format the flash drive back to fat32.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

Windows 10, Creator Update

Format USB Drive as NTFS.  Reboot computer with USB Drive still attached.  Run recovery tool.

After that, the recovery tool saw the USB Drive and I was good to go.